# Calculating Distance Between Two Items in a List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to Calculate the Distance or Length between two items in a list

**Question:** Find the length of the longest subsequence in which the value 6 does not occur. (This number can be zero, if only 6 were in the list.)

For example, in the trial 66423612345654 the longest subsequence which the value 6 does not occur is 12345. and such the distance or length we can say is 5

Note: i have tried using trackers and for loops but i guess i am having trouble with the break positioning maybe

```
Throws=[6,6,2,5,3,6,6,3,6,6,3,6,6,6]
Max=0
Min=0

for i in range (0,len(Throws)):
    Tracker1 = Throws[i]
    if Tracker1==6:
        for k in range (i+1,len(Throws)):
            Tracker2 = Throws[k]
            if Tracker2 ==6 and Throws[k-1]!=6:
                Min = k-i
                if Min>Max:
                    Max=Min
                    break
print(Max)
```

The Max value for the given code should be 3
,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to understand:

```
THROWS = [6, 6, 2, 5, 3, 6, 6, 3, 6, 6, 3, 6, 6, 6]
CONTROL_NUM = 6

max = 0
count = 0

for current in THROWS:
    if current != CONTROL_NUM:
        count += 1
        if count > max:
            max = count
    else:
        count = 0


print(max)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
max(len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(Throws, lambda x: x != 6) if k)
```

**Code**:

```
from itertools import groupby

Throws = [6,6,2,5,3,6,6,3,6,6,3,6,6,6]

print(max(len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(Throws, lambda x: x != 6) if k))
# 3
```

Comment: `max(len(list(g)) for k,g in groupby(Throws, lambda x:x!=6) if k)`

Comment: Thanks, works like magic on the online interpreter, i should learn more about the iterators, for some reason they are not working on my python, probably an update or something, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can use use `join()` and `split()` to convert sequence to string and find the longest distance using the following:

```
throws = [6,6,4,2,3,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4]
max_seq_length = max([len(sub_list)  for sub_list in "".join([str(i) for i in throws]).split("6")])
```

Answer (score 0):

One-line, recursive solution:

```
f = lambda s, v: v in s and max(s.index(v), f(s[s.index(v) + 1:], v)) or len(s)
```

So, in your case:

```
f([6,6,2,5,3,6,6,3,6,6,3,6,6,6], 6))
```

gives `3` as output.

The main idea is that the length of a subsequence not containing a value is the length of the subsequnce between two consecutive occurences of that value. The base case is when the value is not present at all in the sequence, so that the longest subsequence not containing it is the subsequence itself.

The method `index` provides you with the position of the first occurrence of a value, so the length of the prefix of the sequence not containing the value is the value given by the `index` method. Recursively, you can search for the other prefixes, looking at subsequences starting at the immediate position after the occurrence you have just found, til you reach the end of the input sequence.